# Cannot access apache on Centos 7 virtualbox machine

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7

The host machine is Windows 10 and the guest is Centos 7, bridged connection.  From the guest, I can reach the internet just fine.  From the host, I can ping the guest but not access apache via http.

For testing purposes I've turned off iptables.  I've verified httpd is running.  What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Centos 7, then use this command in your guest VM and check from your host browser again.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Comment: Thanks, everything I was looking at said to use iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Allow port 80 to be access from outside:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent  --add-service=http
# firewall-cmd --reload
```